# free causes segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

In the following program, which is intended only for educational purposes, I cannot see why `free()` causes a segmentation fault. In the last loop I try to clean op my double-connected pointer list but even a single `free()` on the `first_node` (outside the loop if I place it there) results in a segmentation fault... Does any body see why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int val;
};

int main() {
    Node *first_node;
    Node *active_node;
    Node *prev_node;
    first_node->val = 0;
    active_node = first_node;
    for (int c = 1; c < 10 ; c = c + 1) {
        active_node->next = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        active_node->next->val = c;
        active_node->next->prev = active_node;
        prev_node = active_node;
        active_node = active_node->next;
    }
    active_node = first_node;
    while (active_node) {
        printf("Node: %d\n", active_node->val);
        prev_node = active_node;
        active_node = active_node->next;
    }

    active_node = first_node;
    while (active_node) {
        prev_node = active_node;
        active_node = active_node->next;
        free(prev_node); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am sure it is the `free()` as when I comment that line out, the program runs fine.

My output looks like this:

```
Node: 0
Node: 1
Node: 2
Node: 3
Node: 4
Node: 5
Node: 6
Node: 7
Node: 8
Node: 9
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: At `first_node->val = 0;` the pointer is not initialized.

Comment: Quite bright and right! Thanks! :)

Comment: For every `free()` there must be a previous `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`first_node` is uninitialized when you perform `first_node->val = 0;`. `active_node` receives the value of this uninitialized pointer and is used for the last node of the list.

It is actually surprising that the program runs at all, you have undefined behavior on the first statement of the `main()` function.

Just initialize `active_node` to `NULL` and fix the intialization code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node {
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
    int val;
};

int main() {
    Node *first_node;
    Node *active_node;
    Node *prev_node;

    first_node = prev_node = NULL;
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c = c + 1) {
        Node *new_node = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
            return 1;
        new_node->val = c;
        new_node->prev = prev_node;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        if (prev_node)
            prev_node->next = new_node;
        else
            first_node = new_node;
        prev_node = new_node;
    }

    active_node = first_node;
    while (active_node) {
        printf("Node: %d\n", active_node->val);
        active_node = active_node->next;
    }

    active_node = first_node;
    while (active_node) {
        prev_node = active_node;
        active_node = active_node->next;
        free(prev_node); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```